# value didn't pass from one dynamic dropdown box to another dynamic dropdown box in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Above is Before select[image: Before select] [image: after select]Above Afterselect

1.Html file

Here i have 3 comboboxes. 
the second combobox is depend on the first one and 3rd should depend on the second combobox.

I tried to display the second one's query(i mean excecuted the php alone) alone its working perfectly.

Simply value is not passing from the second combobox to the php file.                        (data:'sub='+SUB,  //VALUE IS NOT PASSING).
        $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($query);//$rowcount always NULL in the 2nd combobox.

```
    <html><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .select-boxes{width: 280px;text-align: center;}
    select {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        border: 1px double #FB4314;
        color: #55BB91;
        font-family: Georgia;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 39px;
        padding: 7px 8px;
        width: 250px;
        outline: none;
        margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    }
    select option{
        font-family: Georgia;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sem').on('change',function(){
            var SEM = $(this).val();
            if(SEM){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'sta.php',
                    data:'sem='+SEM,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#sub').html(html);
                        $('#staff').html('<option value="">Select sub first</option>'); 
                    }
                }); 
            }else{
                $('#sem').html('<option value="">Select batch first</option>');
                $('#sub').html('<option value="">Select sem first</option>'); 
            }
        });
        $('#sub').on('change',function(){
            var SUB = $(this).val();
            if(1){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'sta.php',
                    data:'sub='+SUB,  //VALUE IS NOT PASSING
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#staff').html(html);
                    }
                }); 
            }else{
                $('#staff').html('<option value="">Select sub first</option>'); 
            }
        });
    }); 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="select-boxes">
       <form name="signup" method="POST" action="feedform.php">
    <br><br><br><br>
   <select id="sem" name="sem">
    <option value="" selected>Select current semester</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select><br><br><br>
        <select name="sub" id="sub">
            <option value="">Select semester first</option>
        </select>

        <select name="staff" id="staff">
            <option value="">Select sub first</option>
        </select>
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2.sta.php

```
<?php
include("../Mine/connection.php");
if(isset($_POST["sem"]) && !empty($_POST["sem"]))
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT course_name FROM subject WHERE semester =".$_POST['sem']);

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select course</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['course_name'].'">'.$row['course_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">course not available</option>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["sub"]) && !empty($_POST["sub"]))
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT staff_name FROM subject WHERE course_name = ".$_POST['sub']);

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select Staff</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['staff_name'].'">'.$row['staff_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Staff not available</option>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Just tried with simulated data (hardcoded <option>s in the PHP code) and works fine (3rd combobox is filled with data after change of 2nd). Maybe the data added into the <option>s are causing the malfunction as they might contain apostrophes, quotation marks, html tags, etc. Can you post your browser console output and check whether the data is returned in correct format?

Comment: @PetrHejda U mean screenshot of the output?.

Comment: Ideally in text format but screen is fine too. It's just to see if there are errors/warnings and if so, what are they.

Comment: Well, there might be tons of reasons. Please post output from the browser console so it's easier to find source of the malfunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forgot to put (') single quotes.

Original Post : [Character data is not passing from php to jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245891/character-data-is-not-passing-from-php-to-jquery)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT staff_name FROM subject WHERE course_name = '".$_POST['sub']."'");
```